# Submit button not submitable after changing text via .value attribute

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to automate a login system but running into some problems, I am entering the username & password like so:

```
document.getElementById('username').value = 'hello'
```

I am doing the same for password but this method does not enable the submit button, something has to be typed into each field manually by me so it appears after I have edited the username & password via .value.

Is there any work around to this?

EDIT: Here is the button I am trying to submit if it helps at all

```
<button type="submit" class="icon-login" ng-disabled="!loginForm.$valid" disabled="disabled"></button>
```

I am trying to submit to a webpage which uses web-sockets that's why I cannot login via POST data. There is no change in the URL even after logging in.

Comment: The line shown has two errors in it: JS is case sensitive. But anyway, if you modify the value of a field from JS, that does *not* trigger a `change` event handler on the field, so if the code that enables/disables the submit button is in an event handler it won't run. You could call that code directly after setting the values.

Comment: should be lowercase 'd' and lowercase 'g' i.e --> document.getElementById('username').value = 'hello'

Comment: document.getElementById('username').value = 'hello'

Comment: sorry guys that was totally my bad, I'm aware of how it is written I just quickly wrote this as I've been at it for a good 6~ hours and honestly so tired of trying I just wanted some help.

Thank you for the heads up about the event handler, I did not know that was a thing honestly. How would i go about calling the code directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
document.form[0].action="your_page_to_redirect"
document.getElementById('username').value="Hello"
document.form[0].onsubmit=function(){
window.location.href("your_url");
}
document.forms[0].submit();

</script>
```

Is that what you want ?

Comment: It is not, I'm trying to login to an external website using Cefsharp which allows you to use javascript inside a C# program. This has to be done because the site I'm trying to login to does not use post data but in fact web sockets. This means the only way I can login is by entering the user & pass into the fields.

The problem is that the fields are not detecting my text, the URL does not change at all as the URL is from an app. I cannot define URLs besides the main one. I cannot click the submit button because editing via .value does not enable the button